# NullPointerException while sending Intent from Broadcast Receiver to Services when App is in background

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am working on an App for which I am setting an alarm with alarmManager and when broadcast receiver received the pending intent I passed it into Service class to show a notification.and also passing an intent to check which type to alarm is being received.but when my app is in background it stops working because it received null value from intent.
Here is my code :

**In MainActivity.java :**

```
     @Override
      protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

            if (id == DIALOG_ID) {
        return new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, kTimePickerListener, 
        hour, min, false);
       }
          return null;
       }

         protected TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener kTimePickerListener =
           new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hourofday, int 
        minutes) {
            hour = hourofday;
            min = minutes;

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            // set selected time from timepicker to calendar

            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
            ServiceManager.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("reqcode", 11);

            // A PendingIntent specifies an action to take in the
            // future
            PendingIntent mPendingIntent = 
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 11, myIntent, 0);

            // set alarm time
             alarmManager = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 
           mPendingIntent);

        }
    };
```

i am sending a pending code with request code 11 and also sending an intent through pendingintent with  **myIntent.putExtra("reqcode", 11);**

**In my ServiceManager.class :**

```
            public class ServiceManager extends BroadcastReceiver 
            {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            int Noti_code = intent.getIntExtra("reqcode",-1);

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context,NotificationService.class);
                  myIntent.putExtra("reqcode", Noti_code);
                  context.startService(myIntent);
              }
            }
```

Here I am getting this code as a **Noti_code** passing it to my NotificationServices.class through Intent.

**Here is NotificationServices.class :**

```
         public class NotificationService extends Service {

         private NotificationManager mManager;

         @Override
           public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              return null;
             }

         @Override
          public void onCreate() {
           super.onCreate();
           }

         @SuppressWarnings({"static-access", "deprecation"})
         @Override
         public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
            super.onStart(intent, startId);

    **int Noti_Code = intent.getIntExtra("reqcode",-2);** //App crashes here

       if (Noti_Code == 11) {
    mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    ShowNotification(getApplicationContext(), mManager);
}
           }

         @Override
          public void onDestroy() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDestroy();
              }
            }
```

When my app is in backgroud
it crashes here **int Noti_Code = intent.getIntExtra("reqcode",-2);**

**Here is my Menifest.xml :**

```
             <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

           <application
              android:allowBackup="true"
              android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
              android:supportsRtl="true"
              android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
          <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name=".Activity_detail" />
      <activity android:name=".History" />

      <service
        android:name=".NotificationService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:stopWithTask="false"/>
     <receiver android:name=".ServiceManager"/>
     </application>
```

**And Here is the Logcat:**

```
     Process: com.spendless.spendless_financiallifestylesavingapp, PID: 3910                                                                     
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service 
     com.spendless.spendless_financiallifestylesavingapp.Services.NotificationService@5f7f8c2 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Intent.getIntExtra(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
                                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
                                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Intent.getIntExtra(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                   at com.spendless.spendless_financiallifestylesavingapp.Services.NotificationService.onStart(NotificationService.java:46)
                                                                                                   at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java)
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java) 
                                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java) 
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java) 
                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
```

Please help me if there is something missing in my code?
**Thanks.**

Comment: your `intent` is null

Comment: This is what i am asking ? where i am missing in my code ? can you explain ?

Comment: probably it is null always when there are no arguments passed.

Comment: Kindly read the code carefully before giving negative impact. i am passing argument to intent, this is where i passed.and also i checked it by debugging if works find when app is in foreground .   int Noti_code = intent.getIntExtra("reqcode",-1);

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context,NotificationService.class);
                  myIntent.putExtra("reqcode", Noti_code);
                  context.startService(myIntent);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have implemented `onStart()` in your `Service`. This is not the correct method. You should implement `onStartCommand()`. The return value from `onStartCommand()` tells Android whether or not to restart your `Service` under certain conditions and how to redeliver any `Intent`s. Using `onStart()` has some backwards compatibility support that automatically provides the value `START_STICKY` to control restart of your `Service`. This tells Android that you want your `Service` restarted all the time.

What you are probably seeing is that Android has restarted your `Service` with a `null` `Intent`. This can happen if Android kills your `Service` and then automatically restarts it (since you return `START_STICKY`).

See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) on `Service` and also `onStart()` and `onStartCommand()`.